# OpenCV read image quality info

Tags: opencv, compression, jpeg

OpenCV let you set, as an example, the JPEG compression factor when saving an image. Is it possible to GET this value while reading an input image?

I'm creating a simple GUI where the user open an image, process it and than he can select the compression factor before saving. I would like to propose the user the original quality first, than he can decide to change it. I think it's what happens in GIMP.
Same question for other formats (png, ...)

Thanks!

MIX

Comment: JPEG is lossy codec, so when saving to JPEG you are further loosing original information, regardless compression factor. In other words you are irreversibly degrading the image, and using same compression factor as original image won't give you same data quality.

Comment: Good point, indeed. Didn't thought about that... So, if I always save with 100% quality, the image size will probably change (more frequency coefficients, ...), but the quality remains the same, since no information will be generated. Right?

Comment: Nope, 100% quality is not good idea for JPEG, because you again won't get same quality as original, but just too large file. Depends on the task, but 80-85% is sweet spot for JPEG, regarding common sense in quality and file size. If you want lossless output just save the file as PNG.